# How I can implement many to many relations on multiple projects in .Net based on Onion architecture?

Tags: dependency-injection, many-to-many, onion-architecture

Based on my projects I have different modules.
For example, one module is Account Management which is designed to manage users, roles, and permissions,...
Another module is Shop management which is designed to manage shop logic.
each module is in a separate folder and all modules in one solution.
And in each folder, I have different layers such as Domain, Application, and infrastructure.

In some cases, these modules' data models are related together and it's required to be refrenced to them, **My question is, in the case of many to many relations between different projects, How can I implement them?**
Because Asp.net don't accept this and when I refrenced two projects it shows a cycle error. But based on .net it's not possible to A-> referenced to B & B-> referenced to A.
I tried to implement many to many relation in multiple projects in .net platform and onion archtucture. I want to found a solution to implement many to many relations in multiple projects in one solution
Would you please help me, how I can implement this?

Comment: I think this question is not really suited for Stack Overflow, because the question is broad and there many possible answers.

Comment: But since you are trying to keep those modules isolated in a highly fashion, you should investigate the concept of a Bounded Context (BC). It seems you have two BCs in your application. Often you'll find that each BC gets its own service, but it's certainly possible to put multiple BCs in a single runnable application. My advise: try to find out how BCs can communicate with one another, while keeping data sharing to a minimum.